# Как переключиться на предыдущую активти?

Tags: android, activity

Как сделать чтоб при определенном действии можно было вернуться на старую активти вызова её заново, т.е грубо говоря выполнить действие кнопки назад, а то если опять открывать старое активити через `startActivity()` по новой, то при нажатии на кнопку назад он возвращает на предыдущие активити с которого перешел.

Comment: Вы не приняли ни одного ответа на ваши вопросы, вам не будут отвечать, если вы не будете принимать правильные ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. вызвать `finish()` у текущего `Activity`, которое надо закрыть.
2. вызвать `onBackPressed()` у текущего `Activity`, которое надо закрыть.